# Multiple Users in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

After 2 full days I have not been able to find a solution.

Here's my issue.

I created a rails app and added Devise. It all works great except for I have 3 devise users: `Users`, `Vendors` and `Admin`.

My problem is that I am trying to create separate login pages for each user. However when I generate devise views and work on the login page it only pulls the HTML from the views/devise/sessions/new page. So whether you go `/admin/sign_up` , `/vendor/sign_up` or `/user/sign_up` you get the exact same devise page from `views/devise/sessions/new`.

How can you have 3 different `devise/sessions/new views`? I want the `User` login and sign up to look different from the `Vendors` and `Admin` logins. I have 3 devise controllers: Users_controller, Vendors_controller, and Admins_controller

I am soooo confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, several things to look at here.

---

## STI

First step is to get your models sorted out.

You mention you want to have `Users`, `Vendors` and `Admin`. I am presuming you've made several models for this, and would like to stipulate now that it will be much more beneficial for you to inherit from *one* model.

The single model you need to use should be `User`, and should extrapolate its functionality through an [STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | type | devise | attributes | created_at | updated_at
end

#app/models/admin.rb
class Admin < User
   #No table necessary
end

#app/models/vendor.rb
class Vendor < User
   #No table necessary
end
```

This will allow you to use each model as if it were completely standalone, yet maintaining the flexibility of extra functionality. I can explain more about it if you need; bottom line is that you'll be FAR better off using this than separate tables.

---

## Views

Next we have the views themselves.

The options you have for your views are as follows:

> 1. Manage the selection with your routes & controllers
> 2. Manage the selection in the views themselves

I would personally keep a single controller and use different views. You're using the same data, so all you need to is to either render different *layouts*, or different *views* entirely...

And, by the way, remember that `Devise` [uses its own controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers). For your purposes, these are `Sessions` and `Registrations` respectively:

```
#config/routes.rb
def devise_path_names
    { sign_in: "login", sign_up: "", registration: "register", sign_out: "logout" }
end

devise_for :users,  path_names: devise_path_names #-> url.com/users/login
devise_for :admins, controllers: { sessions: "devise#sessions", registrations: "devise#registrations" }, path_names: devise_path_names #-> url.com/admins/login
devise_for :vendors, controllers: { sessions: "devise#sessions", registrations: "devise#registrations" }, path_names: devise_path_names #-> url.com/vendors/login
```

The above routes are untested.

It would be inadvisable to use your own controllers for the respective models - you'll have to recreate them each time, making it very [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions). Instead, you'd be able to potentially do something like this:

```
#app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   before_action :set_route

   private

   def set_route
      @route = request.path.split('/')[0]
   end
end
```

This would pass the params you require to the `devise#sessions` controller.

Having said that, you could even just change the styling with the CSS classes in the views themselves:

```
$ rails generate devise:views users

#app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
<%= form_for resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), class: @route do |f| %>
  ...
```

This will allow you to style the form as required in the CSS. It will pull the `@route` param through the url, allowing you to set the styling in the view.

Answer (score 3):

You can generate three different devise models, views and controllers for `Users`, `Admins` and `Vendors`. You can also add devise helpers to your existing models and controllers instead. For views, make sure to use Devise's role-scoped views generator:

```
`rails generate devise:views users` # change `users` to whichever role you are generating
```

Then you can route each role to its own `signup` in `routes.rb` using their `devise_for` helper like so:

```
devise_scope :user do 
  get 'users/login'   to: 'users#sessions#new',  as 'user_login'
end

devise_scope :admin do 
  get 'admins/login',  to: 'admins#sessions#new', as 'admin_login'
end

devise_scope :vendor do
  get 'vendors/login', to: 'vendors#sessions#new', as 'vendor_login'
end
```

#### BUT:

This is not very DRY. I would strongly suggest rethinking your design and creating a single model for `User` with a `role` attribute. Try the [CanCan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan). Here is CanCan's wiki on how to create role-based authorization:https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the CanCan gem.